# Set a cursor on a table inside a table variable

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

All,

Trying to set a cursor on a table value inside a table variable, but it does not work. can anyone comment on how I can fix this?

** the code below is called from another stored procedure which provides the value for the tablename variable **

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usrSetLTDNormDist]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @TableName Sysname,

---...

    DECLARE @SQLCommand1 NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
    Set @RecCursor1 = Cursor For
        Select [Volume], [TRANSDATE] from @TableName'

    EXECUTE dbo.sp_executesql @sqlCommand1  

    -- Open  Cursor
    Open @RecCursor1
    Fetch Next From @RecCursor1
    Into @Volume, @TransDate

---...
```

Comment: Sorry - it's not quite clear - is `@TableName` a *string* or a [table variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms175010.aspx)? Either way, as currently written, this is broken - `EXEC` runs code in a new scope, and scopes can't access variables from outer scopes.

Comment: Damien, please see above, I added the variables to the code. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Add `PRINT @SQLCommand1` between the `DECLARE` and `EXECUTE` statements to review what is actually being executed. Based on your code snippet, you will see

```
Set @RecCursor1 = Cursor For
Select [Volume], [TRANSDATE] from @TableName
```

...that is, the value you set in @TableName is not automagically added to the script. Here's the way I write these things:

```
DECLARE @SQLCommand1 NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQLCommand1 = replace(N'
Set @RecCursor1 = Cursor For
Select [Volume], [TRANSDATE] from <@TableName>'
 ,'<@TableName>', @TableName)

PRINT @SQLCommand1

EXECUTE dbo.sp_executesql @sqlCommand1
```

I use the < > characters to make the replaced values stand out.

Comment: Thank you Philip, but this still does not solve the cursor issue. The query looks OK but for some reason it doesn't assign a value to RecCursor1

Comment: I quite deliberately have very little experience working with cursors. I would imagine that the cursor is created within the session that is generated to run the dynamic SQL, persists for the duration of that (dynamic SQL) session, and is closed when the session is closed--that is, almost immediately.

Comment: Just a thought: can a cursor run against a view? Use dynamic SQL to create a view (which will persist beyond that "create view" session), run the cursor against the view, and then drop the view when you are done. This raises a whole lot of issues (such as "simutaneous views" if the process is run concurrently, what happens if you don't drop the view, and so on), use paranoia-levels of caution if you try something like it.

Answer (score 0):

This script demonstrates the general technique:

```
create table T (ID int not null)
go
insert into T(ID) values (99)
go
declare @TableName sysname
declare @ID int

set @TableName = 'T'

declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = N'declare boris cursor for select ID from ' + 
                               QUOTENAME(@TableName)

exec sp_executesql @SQL

open boris

fetch next from boris into @ID
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    print @ID

    fetch next from boris into @ID
end
close boris
deallocate boris
```

Producing this output:

```
(1 row(s) affected)
99
```

However, I will offer my usual caution - if you're in a situation where you want to operate against *multiple* tables in the same way, this is usually a sign of a broken data model. Usually there ought to be a *single* table with additional columns containing data that serves to differentiate the values.

Comment: Declaring the cursor inside the @SQL string gives me errors when I open it later

Comment: @HDB - I'm showing you a complete script that you can run in a blank database and observe the results. It was tested (and the results shown at the bottom are from SQL Server 2012). I don't know how the above differs from your actual code, because you're the only person well placed to determine that currently.